# How to build and populate DB using JPA entities?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven, jpa

I have `Java Spring` project which is using `CrudRepository` for the entities in the DB (`postgresql`).

I need to have a quick way to use the entities definitions in order to create the DB tables and constraints, I don't want to use SQL queries to do that, or Java code.

Also, I want to create a populator for these entities with fake data, using `maven` plugin.

I was looking in the WEB to find best practices to reach above functionality and I couldn't find.

Comment: Did you see Liquibase: https://www.liquibase.org/

Answer (score 2):

To create the database schema from the entities' definition, you can use the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`.

And for the data initialization, you can create a `data.sql` script at your `resources,` and it will run on the application initialization.

[You can read more about it at the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc).

For a more fine-grained solution, you can use tools like Liquibase and Flyway.

Comment: For me `data.sql` is not read when `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is not `none`. It is only read when `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is `none` so the schema needs to exist. Any idea ?